# Unterschied zwischen einer Sprachvarietät und einem Dialekt am Beispiel Österreichisch?

Tags: dialect, regional, terminology, austrian

In einer [Diskussion](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/11076/) um »korrekte« Aussprache wurde angemerkt, dass das in Österreich gesprochene Deutsch kein Dialekt sei, sondern eine »Standardvarietät der deutschen Hochsprache«.

> Österreichisches Deutsch ist KEIN Dialekt! Es ist eine der drei Standardvarietäten der deutschen Hochsprache.

Worin besteht der Unterschied?

Comment: Nach langem Überlegen komme ich mittlerweile zu der Auffassung, dass diese Frage keine wirklich gute Frage für German Language SE war. Sie kann nicht durch eine einzige gute Antwort beantwortet werden und man könnte Bücher zu diesem Thema schreiben, die dann hauptsächlich linguistische oder politische Überlegungen beinhalten, wie es auch die existierenden Antworten zeigen.

Comment: In dem Sinne friere ich diese Frage hiermit ein. Nochmal zur Klarstellung: Das Problem dieser Frage ist vor allem der Umfang sowie, dass sie eigentlich (mindestens) zwei Fragen ist. Zukünftige Fragen zu derartigen Themen sollten deutlich spezifischer sein, zum Beispiel: »Welche grammatikalischen Unterschiede gibt es zwischen belgischem und deutschem Deutsch?« Fragen zur Klassifizierung von Sprachvarianten sollten nur nach Argumenten fragen und ausufernde Beispiele in den Antworten vermeiden. Idealerweise sollten die Eigenschaften der Sprachvariante in vorherigen Fragen erarbeitet worden sein.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deutsch wird oft als plurizentrische Sprache bezeichnet. Das bedeutet im Wesentlichen, dass es neben den vielen regionalen Dialekten mehrere Varianten der Standardsprache gibt. Die bei weitem wichtigsten sind deutsches Hochdeutsch, österreichisches Hochdeutsch und Schweizer Hochdeutsch.

Mit *Österreichisch* meint man meist österreichisches Hochdeutsch. Die Unterschiede zwischen den verschiedenen Formen von Hochdeutsch sind gering. Sie sind ungefähr mit den Unterschieden zwischen den Hauptvarianten des Englischen vergleichbar. Insbesondere (auf Österreichisch würde man sagen: insbesonders) sind sich die drei Hauptvarianten des Hochdeutschen untereinander sehr viel ähnlicher als mit den jeweiligen regionalen Dialekten, oder als diese untereinander. Wer Hochdeutsch spricht, kann leicht Verständigungsprobleme mit einem reinen Dialektsprecher aus einer fremden Region haben. Mit einem Sprecher einer anderen Variante des Hochdeutschen ist das praktisch ausgeschlossen, weil sich nur einzelne Wörter unterscheiden.

Grund für die Varianten ist offensichtlich, dass die Standardsprache im ständigen Austausch mit den Dialekten steht. Innerhalb jedes Landes besteht eine relativ hohe Mobilität und die landesweiten Medien sorgen für einen ständigen Ausgleich zwischen den dort vertretenen Dialekten. In Deutschland sind im Prinzip alle deutschen Dialektgruppen vertreten, in Österreich zwei (Bairisch und am Westrand auch Alemannisch), in der Schweiz nur eine (Alemannisch). Das macht es Ausdrücken des Bairischen bzw. Alemannischen etwas leichter, in Österreich bzw. der Schweiz in die Standardsprache aufgenommen zu werden. Außerdem ist noch zu beachten, dass auch deutsches Hochdeutsch nicht monolithisch ist. Oft gibt es eindeutig nördliche (*ich habe geschwommen*) und südliche (*ich bin geschwommen*) Varianten mit einer Übergangszone dazwischen. In diesen Fällen ist im Österreichischen und Schweizerischen nur die südliche Variante korrekt.

Dazu kommt noch, dass Wien, das kulturelle Zentrum Österreichs, am äußersten Rand des deutschen Sprachraums liegt und der dortige Dialekt über die österreichischen Medien dem ganzen Land gut vertraut ist. Deshalb sind lokale Wiener Ausdrücke wie *Paradeiser* oder *Fisolen* den Österreichern auch in denjenigen Landesteilen gut bekannt, wo man wie in Deutschland *Tomaten* und *grüne Bohnen* sagt. Da die Deutschen viel weniger österreichische Medienprodukte konsumieren und diese mit Blick auf den großen deutschen Markt teils auch noch absichtlich von spezifisch österreichischen Ausdrücken gesäubert werden, sind diese Wörter dagegen in Deutschland kaum bekannt.

Die Frage, ob es eine »österreichische Sprache« gibt, ist in Österreich selbst von einer gewissen politischen Brisanz. Es ist noch nicht lange her, dass es kein ethnisches Konzept von *deutsch* gab. Deutsch war, wer einen der vielen deutschen Dialekte sprach. Die Entstehung eines Nationalstaates, der sich als *deutsch* bezeichnet, hat die Minderheit der Deutschsprachigen, die nicht Teil dieses Nationalstaates sind, vor das Problem gestellt, ihre Identität neu zu definieren. In der Schweiz und Luxemburg hat man durch Abgrenzung und eine jeweilige mehrsprachige nationale Identität reagiert. In Österreich ist es komplizierter. Das hat z. T. mit der Geschichte zu tun (Anschluss an Deutschland unter den Nazis), z. T. mit der Sprachgeographie: Viele Vorarlberger oder Salzburger haben das Gefühl, mit den deutschsprachigen Schweizern oder den Bayern jenseits der Grenze mindestens genauso viel gemein zu haben, wie mit den Wienern, und jedenfalls mehr als mit der kroatisch sprechenden Minderheit. Durch die Rolle Österreichs als beliebtestes Urlaubsland der Deutschen, und der deutschen Touristen als wichtiger Wirtschaftsfaktor in Österreich, wird das noch befördert.

Es gibt Bestrebungen, das österreichische Hochdeutsch auf einen Kurs weg vom deutschen Hochdeutsch zu bringen, der letztlich zu einer Spaltung wie im Fall des Niederländischen führen könnte. Das Österreichische Wörterbuch könnte man als Teil dieser Bestrebungen interpretieren. Es war gelegentlich Angriffen angesetzt, weil es ost-österreichische, im Westen ungebräuchliche Ausdrücke als "österreichisch" präsentierte. Den in Deutschland erscheinenden und auch in Österreich weit verbreiteten Duden, der großen Wert auf die Darstellung der österreichischen und schweizerischen Varianten legt, kann man andererseits als Teil von entgegengesetzten Bestrebungen ansehen. Und manche Lehrer an Schulen in Österreich unterrichten gezielt deutsches Hochdeutsch, manchmal sogar versehentlich die selteneren norddeutschen Varianten.

In Österreich fehlt z. T. das Gefühl für die Inhomogenität des Hochdeutschen innerhalb Deutschlands. Norddeutsche Ausdrucksweisen fallen sofort auf und werden als Beleg für den Unterschied zwischen Bundesdeutsch und Österreichisch angesehen. Die jeweiligen südlichen Varianten, die oft auch in Deutschland häufiger sind, werden dagegen nicht registriert, weil sie vertraut sind und deshalb nicht auffallen. In Deutschland besteht ein Konsens, dass Süddeutsche es aushalten können müssen, wenn Norddeutsche »das ist nicht an dem« oder »da nicht für« sagen, genauso wie Norddeutsche entsprechende südliche Ausdrücke aushalten müssen. Niemand ist gezwungen, fremd wirkende Ausdrücke zu verwenden. In Österreich scheint z. T. das entsprechende Verständnis bzw. sprachliche Selbstbewusstsein zu fehlen, mit der Folge von unsinnigen Anpassungen an Norddeutsch und natürlichen Abwehrreaktionen darauf.

Die Aussage, dass ein spezielles Wort österreichisch ist, ist relativ unproblematisch. Manche Wörter im Duden sind als *österreichisch, süddeutsch und österreichisch* oder *schweizerisch und österreichisch* (oder so ähnlich) markiert. Das bedeutet dann, dass diese Wörter nur in der jeweiligen Region in der Standardsprache gebräuchlich sind. Natürlich ist der Übergang zwischen standardsprachlichen und Dialektwörtern fließend. Das ist in Österreich aber auch nicht anders als sonst wo.

Comment: Auch in Österreich heißt es mW (ausschließlich) insbesonder**e**. So jedenfalls das ÖWB. 

_Es gibt Bestrebungen, das österreichische Hochdeutsch auf einen Kurs weg vom deutschen Hochdeutsch zu bringen, der letztlich zu einer Spaltung wie im Fall des Niederländischen führen könnte._

Die Gefahr sehe ich nicht. Im Gegenteil, österreichisches Deutsch ist einem ganz massiven Assimilierungsdruck ausgesetzt, dem es auf Dauer wohl auch nicht standhalten wird.

Comment: Dann hab ich wohl als Deutscher, der ein paar Jahre in Österreich gelebt hat, einen ähnlichen Fehler gemacht wie den, den ich für manche österreichischen Lehrer beschrieben habe. Ich hatte den Eindruck, dass *insbesonders* zumindest in Emails verbreiteter als *insbesondere* ist und dachte, das gilt in Österreich als korrekt. (In Deutschland hört man das fast gar nicht.)

Comment: Was den Assimilierungsdruck betrifft: Den gab es von Anfang an. Der Versuch, auf der Basis der Dialekte und Kanzleisprachen der südlichen deutschsprachigen Länder (damals katholisch geprägt), oder auch nur der von Österreich, ein Gegengewicht zum Standard-Hochdeutsch zu schaffen (das ziemlich genau in der Mitte des Sprachraums entstand und z.T. durch die Reformation geprägt war) war endgültig gescheitert, als Maria Theresia Standard-Hochdeutsch bei der Einführung der allgemeinen Schulpflicht zur Schulsprache machte.

Comment: Ähnlichen 'Assimilierungsdruck' gibt es innerhalb Deutschlands, wo es immer wieder divergierende Entwicklungen im Norden und Süden gibt und sich manchmal langsam die eine oder die andere durchsetzt. Österreichisches Deutsch hat aber tatsächlich weniger direkten Einfluss auf deutsches Deutsch als umgekehrt. Das ist aus ähnlichen Gründen, wie z.B. amerikanisches Englisch britisches Englisch stärker beeinflusst als umgekehrt. Und auch Deutsch beeinflusst Niederländisch und die skandinavischen Sprachen stärker als umgekehrt. Und Englisch beeinflusst Deutsch stärker als umgekehrt.

Comment: Mir geht es konkret darum, dass "deutsches" Deutsch (aus Mangel eines besseren Wortes) zunehmend um sich greift und dabei auch Austriazismen massiv verdrängt. Das fängt bei den (Kinder-)Büchern und Zeitschriften an und hört beim Fernsehen noch lange nicht auf. Ich sehe das eher leidenschaftslos, es ist aber Tatsache. Dass daneben auch Dialekte zugunsten einer landesweiten Hochsprache verdrängt werden ist richtig, davon aber zunächst unabhängig.

Answer (score 15):

Alles, was ich im allgemeinen Teil über österreichisches Deutsch sage, gilt sinngemäß auch für schweizerisches Deutsch (nicht zu verwechseln mit Schweizerdeutsch, welches keine Hochsprache, sondern ein Dialekt ist). Da ich im Osten Österreichs lebe (geboren und aufgewachsen in Graz, seit 20 Jahren in Wien), kenne ich das schweizerische Deutsch aber zu wenig, um es im Detail den beiden anderen Standardvarietäten gegenüberzustellen.

---

### Dialekt vs. Hochsprache

Ich glaube, der wichtigste Unterschied zwischen einem Dialekt und einer Standardvarietät ist dieser:

Ein Dialekt wird benutzt, um sich mit anderen Personen mündlich zu unterhalten. Er ist also eine Form der gesprochenen Sprache. Nur selten wird Dialekt niedergeschrieben, und wenn doch, dann geschieht das fast immer nur in einem künstlerischen Kontext (Mundart-Gedichte und Lieder).

Eine Standardvarietät ist hingegen eine Ausprägung der genormten Hochsprache. Das ist die Sprache, die man in Büchern und Zeitungen lesen kann, und die Nachrichtensprecher im Fernsehen sprechen. Die Standardvarietäten werden in der Schule im Deutschunterricht gelehrt und sind die allgemeine Unterrichtssprache an Schulen und Universitäten. Die Standardvarietäten sind mit den jeweiligen Amtssprachen identisch. Das alles trifft auf Dialekte nicht zu.

Bei Dialekten ergibt sich aus der so gut wie nicht vorhandenen Schriftform der Umstand, dass es für Dialekte keine verbindlichen Rechtschreibregeln gibt. Jeder Mundart-Autor verwendet seine eigenen Regeln, die meist von denen eines anderen Autors abweichen.

Anders ist das bei einer Hochsprache wie dem österreichischen Deutsch, das übrigens nicht nur in Österreich gesprochen wird, sondern auch in Teilen Norditaliens (Südtirol). Hier gibt es ganz klare Regeln, die vorgeben, wie ein Wort geschrieben werden muss. Und wer in Österreich oder Italien ein Schüler oder Beamter ist, muss die Wörter auch genau so schreiben, wie sie im [Österreichischen Wörterbuch (ÖWB)](http://www.oebv.at/list.php?page=titelfamilie&titelfamilie=%D6sterreichisches+W%F6rterbuch) vorgegeben sind. Das ÖWB wird vom Staat Österreich (vom Ministerium für Unterricht und Kunst) herausgegeben und ist für Schüler und Beamte verbindlich.

Für das deutsche Deutsch (das auch in Belgien und Luxemburg Amtssprache ist) hatte der Duden bis 1996 eine ähnliche Funktion. Der Duden war aber in Österreich niemals ein verbindliches Nachschlagewerk, und seit 1996 ist der Duden für keine Varietät der deutschen Sprache mehr verbindlich.

---

### Deutsches Deutsch vs. österreichisches Deutsch

Wichtig ist hervorzuheben, dass sich österreichisches Deutsch und deutsches Deutsch voneinander unterscheiden – und das sowohl im Vokabular als auch in den Rechtschreibregeln als auch in der Grammatik.

Die hier angeführten Unterschiede sind nur Beispiele. Es wurden bereits mehrere Bücher mit den Unterschieden dieser beiden deutschen Sprachen gefüllt.

**unterschiedliche Vokabel für gleiche Dinge**

Am bekanntesten dürften Unterschiede im Vokabular sein, und hier vor allem in der Küchensprache. In Österreich gibt es keinen Quark, sondern Topfen. Es gibt keine Aprikosen, sondern Marillen. Der Meerrettich heißt bei uns Kren und das Eisbein ist eine Stelze. Die Erdäpfel werden jedoch ebenso wie die Paradeiser immer mehr von Kartoffeln und Tomaten verdrängt. Das ist auf die Übermacht deutscher Medien auf dem österreichischen Markt zurückzuführen.

Vokabular-Unterschiede gibt es aber auch in anderen Bereichen: In der Straßenverkehrsordnung wird nicht zwischen Vortritt und Vorfahrt unterschieden, das heißt bei uns immer Vorrang. Es gibt in Österreich kein Bußgeld! Wenn wir falsch parken, bezahlen wir ein Organstrafmandat. Und wenn ein Verbrechen geschieht, kommt es zu keiner Tatortbegehung, sondern zu einem Lokalaugenschein.

Der erste Monat im Jahr heißt nicht Januar, sondern Jänner, und wenn die Uhr 8:45 anzeigt, ist es nicht »Viertel vor Neun«, sondern »Dreiviertel Neun«. Die Wurst wird bei uns nicht in Gramm verkauft, sondern in Deka (Kurzform für Dekagramm = 10 Gramm). Also nicht 150 Gramm Wurst, sondern 15 Deka.

Das Wort »pusten« ist bei uns nur als Fremdwort bekannt, wird aber aktiv nicht benutzt. Wir blasen dort, wo Deutsche lieber pusten. Daher gibts in Österreich auch keine Pusteblumen, sondern nur Löwenzahn.

**gleicher Begriff aber unterschiedliche Bedeutung**

Es gibt aber auch Begriffe, die zwar gleich sind, aber etwas anderes bedeuten:

Ich habe gehört, dass in Deutschland streng zwischen einem Stuhl (harte Sitzfläche) und einem Sessel (gepolstert) unterschieden wird. In Österreich ist »Sessel« der Überbegriff für transportable Einpersonen-Sitzmöbel. Man kann in Österreich daher auch auf einem Sessel sehr hart sitzen.

Die Wörter »Fuß« und »Hand« werden auch als Synonyme für »Bein« und »Arm« verwendet. Wer vom Schifahren mit einer Fraktur des Schienbeins zurückkommt, hat sich den Fuß gebrochen.

»Laufen« bedeutet immer rennen. Man kann in Österreich nicht langsam die Straße entlang laufen, um sich anzusehen, was in den Schaufenstern ist. Das ist ein Widerspruch! Langsames Fortbewegen auf Beinen ist niemals laufen! Kleinkinder lernen nicht laufen, sondern gehen. Erst wenn sie einigermaßen gut gehen können, können sie es mit dem Laufen versuchen. Und weil laufen immer dasselbe wie rennen ist, gehen in Österreich auch alle Tiere (solange sie nicht rennen). Ein Huhn geht über die Straße und ein Hund geht neben seinem Herrchen.

Auch gleiche Phrasen können etwas ganz anderes bedeuten. »Mir geht einer ab« wird in Österreich ganz anders verstanden als in Deutschland. Beispiel: Der Schulausflug ist zu Ende, die Schüler steigen in den Bus, der Lehrer zählt mit. Als alle im Bus sind, ruft er laut seiner Kollegin zu »Mir geht einer ab«. Gemeint ist: »Mir fehlt einer meiner Schüler.« (abgehen = fehlen)

Eine geile Torte ist ein Stück Kuchen mit einer besonders fetten Cremefüllung. (geil = fett und süß)

### Grammatik

Auch die Grammatik ist anders. Ein Satz wie »Hans hat beim Abschied aus dem Fenster gewunken.« wäre in deutschem Deutsch falsch, ist in österreichischem Deutsch aber völlig richtig, denn »gewunken« ist ebenso erlaubt wie »gewinkt«.

**Formen der Vergangenheit**

Auch der Gebrauch der Vergangenheitsformen ist unterschiedlich. Die Zeitformen haben sogar unterschiedliche Namen:

Beispiele:

> Ich ging spazieren.

In Deutschland: »Präteritum«, »1. Vergangenheit«, »Nachvergangenheit« oder »unvollendete Vergangenheit«. Wird verwendet, um auszudrücken, dass die Handlung in der Vergangenheit stattgefunden hat und auch in der Vergangenheit abgeschlossen wurde. Es ist die übliche Zeitform für Erzählungen.

In Österreich: »Mitvergangenheit«. Wird in der Alltagssprache kaum verwendet, findet man eigentlich nur in schriftlichen Erzählungen.

> Ich bin spazieren gegangen.

In Deutschland: »Perfekt«, »2. Vergangenheit«, »vollendete Gegenwart« (!) oder »Vorgegenwart«. Es wird ausgedrückt, dass die Handlung bis in die Gegenwart reicht oder unmittelbare Auswirkungen auf die Gegenwart hat.

In Österreich: »Vergangenheit«. In dieser Zeitform wird alles ausgedrückt, was in der Vergangenheit stattgefunden hat, unabhängig davon, ob es Auswirkungen auf die Gegenwart hat oder nicht.

> Ich war spazieren gegangen.

In Deutschland: »Plusquamperfekt«, »3. Vergangenheit«, »vollendete Vergangenheit« oder »Vorvergangenheit«. Die Handlung wurde vor einem anderen Ereignis, das in der Vergangenheit liegt, abgeschlossen.

In Österreich: »Vorvergangenheit«. Wird gleich wie in Deutschland verwendet, im Alltag aber häufig durch andere Formulierungen vermieden.

**Artikel/Geschlecht**

Viele Substantiva haben im österreichischen Deutsch andere Artikel als im deutschen Deutsch.

Bekannt ist vielleicht noch dieser Werbespruch für Red Bull Cola (Red Bull ist ein österreichisches Unternehmen):

> Das Cola von Red Bull.

[Das Cola von Red Bull http://www.designtagebuch.de/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/das-cola.jpg](http://www.designtagebuch.de/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/das-cola.jpg)

Das ist ganz korrektes österreichisches Deutsch, weil Cola bei uns nicht weiblich, sondern sächlich ist. Auch das Fanta ist sächlich.

Zahlwörter sind auch nicht weiblich, sondern männlich:

> Ich habe einen Einser auf meine Schularbeit bekommen.
>   Mit welcher Straßenbahnlinie kommt man nach Ottakring? – Mit dem Sechsundvierziger.

**Rechtschreibung**

Aber auch dann, wenn die Grammatik und der Wortschatz gleich sein sollten, gibt es noch Unterschiede bei der Rechtschreibung, allerdings sind diese Fälle selten:

»Nachhause«, »zuhause« und »ohneweiters« werden bevorzugt zusammengeschrieben. Die getrennte Schreibweise ist erlaubt, aber unüblich.

Da das »o« in »Geschoß« (Stockwerk; Projektil) in Österreich als langes o gesprochen wird, steht dieses Wort mit einem scharfen S im ÖWB (Österreichisches Wörterbuch).

Übrigens: Der Buchstabe »ß« heißt im deutschen Deutsch »Eszett«, in Österreich aber »scharfes S«. Und im schweizerischen Deutsch gibt es diesen Buchstaben gar nicht. Wenn in Deutschland oder Österreich ein ß gefordert ist, wird in der Schweiz ein Doppel-S verwendet. Daher hatten viele Schweizer Schreibmaschinen zwar Z und Y dort, wo man sie auch bei deutschen Schreibmaschinen montiert hat, aber ihnen ging der Buchstabe »ß« ab.

**Fugenlaute**

Fugenlaute werden im österreichischen Deutsch sehr häufig anderes gesetzt als im deutschen Deutsch:

- Nicht Schweinebraten, sondern Schweinsbraten (s statt e)
- Nicht Adventskalender, sondern Adventkalender (kein Fugenlaut)
- Nicht Zugverspätung, sondern Zugsverspätung (hier kommt ein s rein)
- Nicht Haltverbot, sondern Halteverbot (ohne e wäre es falsch)

---

### Aussprache

Ich stelle diesem Abschnitt einige Sätze aus [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussprache_der_deutschen_Sprache) voran:

> Die deutsche Sprache ist plurizentrisch, das heißt, es gibt faktisch keine einheitliche Aussprache des Standarddeutschen für den gesamten deutschen Sprachraum. Die als Norm formulierte Standardaussprache ist eine Fiktion, die zwar als (angeblich) einheitliches Ideal gilt, aber praktisch in unterschiedlichen Varianten realisiert und auch in ihrem Ideal durchaus voneinander abweichend verstanden wird.
>   […]
>   Es ist daher unrealistisch zu sagen, dass allein eine dieser verschiedenen Aussprachen des Standarddeutschen die »richtige« wäre (und dem einen Ideal entspräche) und alles andere dialektgefärbte Abweichungen.
>   […]
>    Das Übergewicht der Normvariante aus der Bundesrepublik ist allein als ein quantitatives zu beschreiben […]. Aber auch innerhalb Deutschlands lassen sich Unterschiede feststellen, wenn man z. B. die Aussprache bayerischer und norddeutscher Radio- und Fernsehsprecher vergleicht.

Vor dem Hintergrund eines Vergleichs der Standardvarietäten muss man in Bezug auf die Aussprache festhalten, dass sie weit weniger von der Standardvarietät abhängt, als man vielleicht vermuten wird. Das wird deutlich, wenn man sich Orte im Grenzgebiet anschaut:

Passau in Deutschland und Schärding in Österreich sind voneinander rund 10 km entfernt. In Passau wird an (nicht in!) den Schulen deutsches Deutsch unterrichtet, in Schärding wird in (nicht an!) den Schulen österreichisches Deutsch gelehrt. (Kleiner Exkurs: In Österreich geht man nicht zur Schule, sondern in die Schule. Der Unterricht findet nicht an, sondern in einer Schule statt, denn in Österreich versteht man unter einer Schule primär das Gebäude in dem unterrichtet wird, nicht die Institution.)

Und obwohl die Bürger von Passau und Schärding zwei unterschiedliche Hochsprachen eingetrichtert bekommen haben, kann man anhand ihrer Aussprache nicht unterscheiden, wer aus welcher Stadt stammt. Hört man aber einen Kellner aus Dresden und einen aus Mainz sprechen, wird man deutliche Unterschiede heraushören, und das auch dann, wenn beide keinen Dialekt sprechen, sondern jene Sprache, die in Dresden bzw. Mainz für akzentfreies Hochdeutsch gehalten wird.

Ebenso hört man beim Vergleich von Sprechern aus Graz (dort habe ich die ersten ca. 30 Jahre meines Lebens verbracht) und Wien (hier wohne ich seit ca. 20 Jahren) deutliche und markante Unterschiede. Und ich betone nochmals: Ich meine hier nur Sprecher, die akzentfreies Hochdeutsch sprechen.

Die Variationen der Aussprache an der Standardvarietät festzumachen, ist daher falsch. Das eine ist nicht die Ursache des anderem. Trotzdem wird in Österreich natürlich vieles anders ausgesprochen als in den meisten Gegenden Deutschlands, aber diese Sprachgrenze ist nicht mit der Staatengrenze identisch, sondern verläuft weiter nördlich. Vieles, was ich im Folgenden über Österreich sage, gilt auch für Altbayern (Oberpfalz, Niederbayern und Oberbayern). Jedoch muss man insbesondere das westlichste österreichische Bundesland Vorarlberg wieder aus einigen der folgenden Behauptungen ausschließen, weil dort der Einfluss der schweizerischen Sprechweise deutlich größer ist als der bairisch-österreichische.

**/ɛː/ wird wie /eː/ ausgesprochen**

Der Laut /ɛː/ (ä in Käse) fällt im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums mit /eː/ (erstes e in Lese) zusammen. Aus dem gesprochenen Satz »Im Wald sind B[ä|ee]ren.« kann man bei korrekter österreichischer Aussprache also nicht heraushören, ob sich Raubtiere oder Früchte im Wald befinden.

**/b, d, ɡ, z, ʒ/ sind stimmlos**

Das B in »Biene«, das D in »Laden«, das G in »Lager«, das S in »Wiese« und das SCH in »Plantage« sind stimmlos. Das Genie und die Schere beginnen in Österreich also mit demselben Konsonanten (nämlich demselben wie in Schule). Ebenso beginnen »sechs« und »Sekt« mit demselben Konsonanten, den man auch in »Straße« und »Last« findet.

**Es gibt keine Auslautverhärtung**

Dieser Vorgang ist den meisten deutschen Muttersprachlern gar nicht bewusst, und daher hinderlich beim Erwerb von Fremdsprachen, wo die Auslautverhärtung dann auch gemacht wird, obwohl es sie z. B. im Englischen nicht gibt.

Darunter ist zu verstehen, dass Konsonanten, die im Inneren eines Wortes weich gesprochen werden, zu harten Konsonanten werden, wenn sie ans Ende des Wortes rutschen.

Beispiele:
Das b in »reiben« wird als weiches b gesprochen. Aber das b in »rieb« wird in weiten Teilen Deutschlands wie ein hartes p gesprochen. In Österreich (und, soweit mit bekannt ist, auch in der Schweiz) hingegen bleibt das b weich.

**deutlich hörbare Konsonantenschwächung**

Die binnendeutsche Konsonantenschwächung zieht sich durch viele Gegenden des deutschen Sprachraums. Dabei werden harte Konsonanten (Fortes) durch ihre weiche Geschwister (Lenes) ersetzt. Die »Leiter« ist dann lautlich nicht mehr vom Wort »leider« zu unterscheiden, »reißen« ist von »reisen« nicht zu unterscheiden und der »Keil« ist »geil«.

Vielerorts (vor allem in Wien und Umgebung, wo rund ein Drittel aller Österreicher lebt) wird der Teppich als »Deebich« und der Kakao als »Gaugoh« ausgesprochen, jedoch ist davon 150 km weiter südlich, in Graz nichts mehr zu bemerken.

**Das g in König bleibt ein g**

In Deutschland: Im Satz »Der König ist selig, wenn er Honig isst.« wird dreimal die Endsilbe -ig wie »-ich« ausgesprochen: »Der Könich ist selich, wenn er Honich isst.« Wäre das nicht der Fall, würde die (meist unbewusst gemachte) Auslautverhärtung zuschlagen und den Satz wie folgt klingen lassen: »Der Könik ist selik, wenn er Honik isst.« In Österreich wird beides nicht gemacht. König, selig und Honig werden mit g am Ende gesprochen.

**kein /ç/ (»ch«) als Silbenanlaut**

Die einzige Silbe, die in Österreich mit dem Reibelaut /ç/ beginnt, ist die Verkleinerungssilbe -chen (Kleidchen, Mädchen).

Links die richtige Schreibweise, rechts die österreichische Aussprache:

> China – Kina
>   Chemie – Kemie
>   Champignon – Schampio
>   Charlotte – Scharlotte
>   Recherche –  Reschersche
>   chatten – tschetn
>   Chile – Tschiile

**Das r wird im Mund weiter vorne gebildet**

Der Konsonant R wird in Österreich selten unter Beteiligung des Gaumens gebildet, sondern am vorderen Zahndamm.

---

### Landkarten

[Verbreitung der deutschen Hochsprachen](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sprachvariet%C3%A4ten_Deutsch.png)

[Verbreitung der deutschen Dialekte](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Deutsche_Dialekte.PNG)

---

### Nachtrag

Der österreichische Radiosender Ö1 strahlte am Sonntag, den 6. April 2014 eine Talkshow zum Thema »Österreichisches Deutsch« aus, und von Montag 7.4. bis Donnerstag 10.4. waren vier Folgen der Sendereihe »Radiokolleg« diesem Thema gewidmet.

Ich habe diese fünf Radiosendungen als mpeg-Dateien aufgenommen und kann sie auf Anfrage gerne per E-Mail weitergeben. Da ich keine Rechte an diesen Sendungen habe, darf ich sie nicht öffentlich zum Download bereitstellen, daher wirklich nur nach Anfrage per E-Mail. (Meine E-Mail-Adresse steht in meinem Profil.)

**Inhalt der Sendungen**
*Café Sonntag*
Talkshow, Dauer 50 Minuten, ca. 50 % Text, 50 % Musik
Zu Gast bei Mercedes Echerer ist Dr. Herbert Fussy, Chefredakteur des »Österreichischen Wörterbuchs«.
Zwischendurch gibt es auch humoristische Zuspielungen von Joesi Prokopetz (Kabaretist) und Elfriede Ott (Schauspielerin) zu hören sowie einen kurzen Ausschnitt aus der Sendung »Die Sprachpolizei«, die bis 1978 im ORF lief.

*Radiokolleg – Hüferl, Kren und Powidl*
Populärwissenschaftliches Magazin. Vier Sendungen mit jeweils 15 Minuten Dauer (nur Text, keine Musik)
Themenauswahl:
- Dialekt, Umgangssprache oder Hochsprache?
- gesprochenes und geschriebenes Deutsch
- Österreichisches Deutsch als Unterrichts- und Bildungssprache
- Plurizentrische Sprachen
- Aussprache (Aussprachedatenbank für österr. Deutsch)
- Rechtliche Verbindlichkeit österreichischer Ausdrücke in der EU.
- Probleme von fremdsprachigen Dolmetschern mit österreichischem Deutsch
- wahrgenommene Wertigkeit der Varietäten (Selbst- und Fremdwahrnehmung)
- Deutsch als Fremdsprache.
- Sprach-Ekel (bei Deutschen, wenn sie österreichisches Deutsch hören, aber auch umgekehrt)
- Einfluss der Religionen auf die Varietäten.
- …

Comment: Ich habe meiner Antwort einen Nachtrag angefügt mit dem Angebot Aufnahmen von Radiosendungen zum Thema "österreichisches Deutsch" an Interessierte weiterzugeben.

Comment: Alles sehr schön, aber ich sehe nicht, wie das die Frage beantwortet.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Die Frage lautete: "Was ist der Unterschied zwischen einer Spachvarietät und einem Dialekt?" Die Antwort darauf kannst du direkt nach der Einleitung im Abschnitt "Dialekt vs. Hochsprache" nachlesen.

Comment: Eben, nur jener Abschnitt beantwortet die Frage. Der Rest mag Dir ja sehr am Herzen liegen, gehört meiner Meinung nach aber nicht hierher.

Comment: Ich fand die Unterschiede in dem Text arg konstruiert. Halb Deutschland nutzt das Perfekt als Standardvergangenheit oder sagt Könik anstatt Könich. China, Schina, Kina gibt es kreuz und quer.

Comment: "Das r wird im Mund weiter vorne gebildet" - Bin Grazer, verwende ein Gaumen-R und habe in meiner Umgebung noch nie ein Zungen-R gehört.

Comment: @wolfgang Das deutlichere R ist zumindest in der Hochsprache schon seit längerem am Aussterben. Früher war es jedoch tatsächlich charakteristisch für die Hochsprache des Südens, wie man aus älteren Interviews etc. heraushören kann.

Answer (score 14):

**Achtung!**
Diese Antwort beantwortet nicht die hier gestellte Frage »Was ist der Unterschied zwischen einer Sprachvarietät und einem Dialekt?«, sondern wurde ursprünglich als Antwort auf diese Frage gepostet: [Was ist mit »Österreichisch« gemeint (in sprachlicher Hinsicht)?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/was-ist-mit-%C3%96sterreichisch-gemeint-in-sprachlicher-hinsicht)

Warum der Moderator sie hierher verschoben hat, weis nur er, sie gehört aber nicht hierher. Wenn in dieser Antwort also auf die gestellte Frage referenziert wird, ist damit »Was ist Österreichisch?« gemeint.

Doch nun die eigentliche Antwort auf die Frage
**Was ist mit »Österreichisch« gemeint (in sprachlicher Hinsicht)?**

---

### Dialekt?

Einen österreichischen Dialekt gibt es nicht. In Österreich wird eine Vielzahl an Dialekten gesprochen, von denen die meisten (aber nicht alle) zu den bairischen Dialekten zu zählen sind.

Selbst ein Hamburger oder ein Berliner wird den Dialekt eines Tirolers von dem eines Wieners unterscheiden können. Wenn ein Vorarlberger seinen Dialekt spricht, wird man ihn sogar eher für einen Schweizer als für einen Österreicher halten, und wenn sich ein Kärntner mit einem Südburgenländer unterhält, wird auch ein Bewohner des Ruhrgebietes einen deutlichen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Sprechern hören.

Der Vorarlberger Dialekt ist kein bairischer Dialekt, sondern ein ostalemannischer, der mit den Dialekten des übrigen Bundesgebietes kaum etwas zu tun hat. Dieser Dialekt gehört - wie auch alle in der Schweiz gesprochenen Dialekte und das Schwäbische - zu den west-oberdeutschen Dialekten.

In Tirol, vor allem im Westen und südlich des Alpenhauptkammes, also auch in Osttirol und dem in Italien gelegenen Südtirol, wird ein ost-oberdeutscher Dialekt gesprochen, den Linguisten als *südbairisch* oder *alpenbairisch* bezeichnen. Zur selben Dialektgruppe gehört auch das was in Kärnten gesprochen wird.

Im Rest Österreichs (nordöstliche Hälfte Nordtirols, Salzburg, Ober- und Niederösterreich, Wien, Steiermark und Burgenland) werden ebenfalls ost-oberdeutsche Dialekte gesprochen, die aber als *mittelbairisch* oder *donaubairisch* bezeichnet werden und sich deutlich hörbar von den südbairischen Dialekten unterscheiden.

Eine Besonderheit stellt das Bundesland Steiermark dar, weil hier sowohl nord- als auch mittel- als auch südbairische Dialekte gesprochen werden. (Südbairisch in der Weststeiermark, Nordbairisch im Süden der Ost-Steiermark, Mittelbairisch in der gesamten Obersteiermark). Diese etwas seltsam anmutende Verteilung ist auf Wanderbewegungen im Spätmittelalter zurückzuführen.

Besonders wichtig im Zusammenhang mit der Fragestellung ist aber zu betonen, dass die hier besprochenen Dialekte nicht nur in Österreich gesprochen werden. Dass der alpenbairische Dialekt Tirols auch in Italien gesprochen wird, habe ich bereits erwähnt, und dass man die in Vorarlberg gesprochenen alemannischen Dialekte eher mit der Schweiz in Verbindung bringt, ebenso.

Die bairischen Dialekte, die man in Österreich hört, sind aber so eng mit den Dialekten verwandt, die man im deutschen Bundesland Bayern hört, dass dieses Bundesland sogar namensgebend für diese Dialekt-Familie war. Tatsächlich leben auch in Bayern mehr Sprecher dieser Dialektgruppe als in Österreich.

Aus Sicht der Sprachwissenschaften gibt es daher keinen Grund, die Existenz eines Dialekts zu postulieren, den man als »österreichisch« bezeichnen könnte. Im Gegenteil. Aus den oben genannten Gründen wäre eine solche Bezeichnung gleich aus zwei Gründen irreführend:

1. »Österreichisch« (als Dialekt) wird innerhalb Österreichs so unterschiedlich gesprochen, dass es nicht gerechtfertigt ist, diese Art zu Sprechen als einen einzelnen Dialekt anzusehen.
2. »Österreichisch« (als Dialekt) wird im Ausland (vor allem in Deutschland und Italien) insgesamt von mehr Menschen gesprochen als im Inland (Österreich). Daher ist es auch aus diesem Grund nicht sinnvoll einen Dialekt, oder eine Gruppe von Dialekten als »österreichisch« zu bezeichnen.

---

### Hochsprache?

Im Unterschied zu einem Dialekt ist eine Hochsprache standardisiert. In einer standardisierten Sprache gibt es verbindliche Rechtschreibregeln, in einem Dialekt nicht. Das liegt daran, dass Dialekte nur selten verschriftlicht werden. Wenn das doch geschieht, dann meist in Ausübung von Kunst (Mundart-Dichterei, Mundart-Lieder), wobei jeder Autor dann seine eigenen individuellen Regeln anwendet, die sich sehr oft von den Regeln anderer Dialekt-Autoren unterscheiden.

Dialekte werden nicht benutzt um Texte für Tageszeitungen zu schreiben. Nachrichtensprecher in Radio und Fernsehen sprechen auch keine Dialekte, und vor allem ist die Sprache, die man in Schulen im Zuge des Unterrichts den Kindern beibringt, und nach deren verbindlichen Regeln die Arbeiten der Schüler korrigiert werden, kein Dialekt.

Das alles trifft aber auf eine standardisierte Hochsprache zu.

**Hat nun Österreich einen eigenen Standard für die deutsche Hochsprache?**

Ja. Klar, eindeutig und definitiv: Ja.

Dieser Standard heißt »Österreichisches Deutsch«. Das Vokabular dieser Sprache wird seit 1951 im ÖWB (Österreichisches Wörterbuch) dokumentiert. Dieses Wörterbuch ist ein amtliches Wörterbuch, das von der österreichischen Bundesregierung herausgegeben wird (konkret von jenem Ministerium, das für den Unterricht an Österreichs Schulen zuständig ist, derzeit ist dies das »Bundesministerium für Bildung und Frauen«). Das ÖWB, beziehungsweise dessen Inhalt, ist für Österreichs Schüler und Bundesbeamte verbindlich. Das heißt, dass Schüler bei allem, was sie für die Schule schreiben, sich an das halten müssen, was im ÖWB steht, und dasselbe gilt für alle Bundesbeamte wenn sie in Ausübung ihres Amtes Schriftstücke verfassen (z.B. Polizeiprotokolle). Der Duden war in Österreich niemals ein verbindliches Wörterbuch.

Wichtig, im Zusammenhang mit der Fragestellung, ist zu betonen, dass sich das österreichische Deutsch von anderen Standards der deutschen Sprache unterscheidet. Das österreichische Deutsch kennt Vokabel, die in anderen deutsche Sprachen nicht vorkommen:

- die Abwasch
- der Jänner
- der Bartwisch
- die Delogierung
- die Fisole
- die Trafik
- das Sackerl

Die Grammatik ist teilweise anders. Die grammatischen Zeiten haben sogar andere Namen, so heißt z.B. das Präteritum in Österreich »Mitvergangenheit« und wird auch anders verwendet als in Deutschland. Das Zeichen, mit dem man Teilsätze voneinander trennt, heißt in Österreich »Beistrich« (Der Begriff »Komma« wird aber auch verwendet). Verben heißen in Österreich »Zeitwörter«.

Viele Wörter haben einen anderen Artikel:

- das Cola
- der Spray
- das Keks
- der Zwiebel
- der Einser

Einige Phrasen sind anders:

- Der Greißler bietet Semmeln *um* 30 Cent an.
- Wir fahren *auf* Urlaub.
- Das Essens steht *am* Tisch.
- Lisa geht schon *in die* Schule.
- Es ist schon *dreiviertel acht*.
- Der Hund *geht* neben seinem Herrl.

Und einige Wörter werden anders geschrieben:

- Das *Geschoß* flog nicht sehr weit.
- Ja, das geht *ohneweiters*.

Diese Regeln gelten **nur** in Österreich (und aus historischen Gründen auch in Südtirol), dort sind sie aber (für Schüler und Beamte) verbindlich. Auch wichtig: Die Regeln dieser Sprache sind im gesamten österreichischen Staatsgebiet gültig. Sie gelten also in Vorarlberg genauso wie im Burgenland oder wie in jedem anderen Bundesland, obwohl sich die Dialekte dieser Länder teilweise erheblich voneinander unterscheiden.

Diese Standardvarietät der deutschen Hochsprache erfüllt also perfekt alles, was man von einer Sprache erwartet, die man als »Österreichisch« bezeichnet.

---

### Fazit

**Österreichisch ist kein Dialekt ...**

Die Vermutung, mit »Österreichisch« wäre ein Dialekt gemeint, ist falsch. Die in Österreich gesprochenen Dialekte sind untereinander zu unterschiedlich, haben aber zugleich zu starke Ähnlichkeiten mit ausländischen Dialekten, um die Bezeichnung »österreichisch« für die in Österreich gesprochenen Dialekte zu gerechtfertigten.

**... sondern eine standardisierte Hochsprache.**

Österreichisches Deutsch existiert hingegen als wohldefinierte und standardisierte Hochsprache, also als eine Sprache in der Tageszeitungen gedruckt werden, als eine Sprache die an Schulen nach standardisierten Regeln unterrichtet wird, und als eine Sprache, die Nachrichtensprecher in Radio und Fernsehen verwenden. Diese Sprache ist nicht nur standardisiert, sondern unterscheidet sich in vielen Details auch von den beiden anderen standardisierten deutschen Hochsprachen (Deutsches Deutsch und Schweizerisches Deutsch). Und sie wird im gesamten Staatsgebiet Österreichs geschrieben und gesprochen, außerhalb der Grenzen Österreich (und Südtirols) jedoch kaum.

Wenn man in Bezug auf Sprachen von »Österreichisch« spricht, kann damit also nur die standardisierte Hochsprache »Österreichisches Deutsch« gemeint sein, nicht aber ein Dialekt.

Comment: Mir feht hier der [Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/rat/laender.html) als derzeit einzige überstaatliche Instanz, die Empfehlungen zur deutschen (Hoch-)Sprache gibt und auch für Österreich zuständig ist. Wenn die österreichischen Kultusminister und Beamten hier immer noch eigene Regeln aufstellen, werden hoffentlich auch die Empfehlungen dieses Rates berücksichtigt. In Deutschland hat man den Weg eines eigenen Regelwerks inzwischen verlassen (ehemals Duden) und erklärt die Empfehlungen des Rates als "amtlich".

Comment: "Verben heißen in Österreich »Zeitwörter«." - im Lauf meiner Schulzeit, die vollständig in Baden-Württemberg stattfand, bin ich (je nach Vorliebe des Lehrers und/oder des aktuellen Deutsch-Buchs) an den Bezeichnungen *Verb*, *Tuwort*, *Tunwort* und auch *Zeitwort* vorbeigekommen. So speziell österreichisch scheint also *Zeitwort* nicht zu sein.

Comment: @Takkat: Ich hege die sehr starke Vermutung, dass man sich die Redaktion des ÖWB an die Empfehlungen des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung hält, weis das aber nicht mit Sicherheit. Aber Sprache ist ja mehr als Rechtschreibung. Hinsichtlich der Rechtschreibung gibt es ohnehin kaum Unterschiede (außer *Geschoß* mit ß und dem zusammengeschriebenen *ohneweiters* fällt mir ohnehin kein Rechtschreib-Unterschied ein.) Hinsichtlich des Vokabulars und der Grammatik gibt es hingegen teilweise recht große Unterschiede. p.S.: In Österreich gibt es keinen Kultusminister sondern eine Unterrichtsministerin.

Comment: Der Antwort möchte ich hinzufügen, dass es umgekehrt auch im Deutschen einige Wörter gibt, die im Österreichischen nicht vorkommen. Lecker fällt mir auf die Schnelle als Beispiel ein. Durch die mittlerweile fast flächendeckende Verbreitung von Satelliten- bzw Kabelfernsehen in Österreich empfangen die meisten Haushalte deutsche Fernsehsender. Dadurch und durch das Internet haben sich mittlerweile sehr viele deutsche Wörter und teilweise auch deutsche Grammatik in der österreichischen Umgangssprache etabliert.

Comment: Der letzte Satz ist falsch. ZItat: "Wenn man in Bezug auf Sprachen von »Österreichisch« spricht, kann damit also nur die standardisierte Hochsprache »Österreichisches Deutsch« gemeint sein,..." Der Dialekt kann sehr wohl gemeint sein, denn gemeint ist immer das, was der Sprecher denkt. Das "kann" solltest du gegen ein "sollte" oder etwas ähnliches tauschen.

Comment: Einige der Beispiele für österreichisches Deutsch sind in Wirklichkeit Beispiele für südliche Varianten von Hochdeutsch, die teils häufiger sind als die nördlichen (Norddeutschland ist weniger dicht besiedelt): An "Semmeln um 30 Cent" ist auch in Bayern und Franken nur der niedrige Preis bemerkenswert. In der gesamten südlichen Hälfte Deutschlands gehen Kinder "in die Schule"; "zur Schule" wirkt dort genauso gestelzt wie in Österreich. Die Zeitangabe "dreiviertel acht" ist mindestens von Saarland und Pfalz bis nach Sachsen Standard.

Comment: PS: Auch in deutschen Schulen bekommt man "einen Einser", wenn man sich anstrengt. Zumindest im Süden. Der Unterschied ist nur, dass es da Umgangssprache ist und Lehrer außerhalb Bayerns dazu neigen, "eine Eins" zu sagen, um sich gewählt auszudrücken.

Comment: Mir fallen noch ein (zur Liste Beistrich etc): das "Anbot" ist definitiv österreichisch (in Deutschland unbekannt). Oder "benützen" während man in Deutschland "benutzen" schreibt.

Comment: @hvb: Die Unterschiede zwischen österreichischem und deutschen Deutsch füllen bereits so viele Bücher, dass man damit ganze Regalwände vollkriegt.

Comment: Was mir grad eingefallen ist: in einem anderen Thread meckerst du darüber das in DWDS viele Wörter fehlen, die in Österreich täglich benutzt werden.Nun ja... das DWDS ist ein Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprachen. Na klar gibt's da keine Österreichischen Einträge. Genauso wie keine franzöischen.

Comment: @Emanuel: "Meckern" klingt ein wenig abwertend. Die offizielle Bezeichnung meiner Muttersprache lautet »Österreichisches Deutsch«. Das ist eine der drei Standard-Varietäten der Deutschen Sprache, also »Deutsch«. »Österreichisch« ist ebenso wenig eine offizielle Sprachbezeichnung wie »Brasilianisch« oder »Amerikanisch«. Dennoch werden diese Begriffe verwendet (in vielen Büchern steht: »Aus dem Amerikanischen übersetzt von ...«). Meine Frage galt der Definition von »Österreichisch«. Nirgendwo wurde behauptet, Österreichisch (oder Österreichisches Deutsch) wäre etwas anderes als Deutsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: warum stellst du diese Frage, wenn du sie am gleichen Tag noch umfangreich selbst beantwortest?

Comment: @Takkat: Darf ich fragen, was dich dazu bewogen hat, die ursprüngliche Frage zu löschen und die zur ursprünglichen Frage gepostete Antwort hierher zu verschieben? In der ursprünglichen Frage ding es darum, ob "österreichisch" ein Dialekt oder eine Sprache ist. Das geht jetzt wieder unter. **sauer bin**

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: deine Antwort passt zu dieser Frage hier doch genausogut, oder? Deine andere Frage war sehr umstritten, das hast du ja mitbekommen. Bevor nun ein Close-Reopen-Flag-Delete-War losgetreten wird, habe ich mich für diesen Weg entschieden, der (außer meiner Antwort) alle der vielen schönen Antworten stehen lässt. Ich frage ja hier auch nach "Dialekt", deshalb passt alles ganz prima.

Comment: @falkb: Es ist völlig in Ordnung seine eigenen Fragen zu beantworten. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @raznagul: hat was von Selbstdarstellung, wenn man etwas fragt und unmittelbar darauf hier einen Roman postet, denn dann wollte man die Antworten der Anderen gar nicht lesen.

Comment: @falkb: Wenn du hier eine Frage stellst, hast du die Möglichkeit, **zugleich** auch schon eine Antwort dafür zu verfassen. Frage und Antwortwort erscheinen dann zugleich in genau derselben Millisekunde. Natürlich war es **nicht** meine Absicht, mit meiner Frage die Meinung anderer einzuholen, sondern damit die vom System angebotene (und auch genau für solche Fälle vorgesehene) Möglichkeit zu nutzen, in einer Antwort einen wichtigen Sachverhalt darzustellen. Das heißt aber nicht, dass ich andere Antworten, die naturgemäß erst nach meiner eigenen Antwort erscheinen konnten, nicht gelesen hätte.

Comment: Hah, hier wird die politische mit der sprachwissenschaftlichen Dimension aber vermengt bis letztere nicht mehr erkennbar ist.

Answer (score 7):

Eine Sprachvarietät ist eine eigene vollwertige "Sprache in der Sprache". Einzelne Varietäten unterscheiden sich durch Unterschiede im Vokabular, aber durchaus auch in der Grammatik. Es sind in aller Regel Schriftsprachen mit fester Schreibweise.

Klassische Beispiele sind eben Britisches und Amerikanisches (oder Kanadisches, Indisches etc.) Englisch: Alle natürlich "Englisch", aber sowohl in der Grammatik als auch im Vokabular gibt es deutliche Unterschiede.

Answer (score 5):

Die Frage, ob ein Wort „österreichisch“ ist, ist überhaupt keinen Millimeter problematisch, denn „österreichisch“ wird hier als Adjektiv verwendet und ist in jedem Wörterbuch klar definiert zu finden.
Ein „österreichisches Wort“ ist ein Wort aus Österreich, genau wie österreichischer Wein Wein aus Österreich ist. In diesem Zusammenhang spielt es gar keine Rolle, was „das Österreichische“ an sich ist.
Um das wiederum zu beantworten, kann man verschiedene Ansätze wählen. Einer wäre, objektiv zu definieren, was eine Sprache und einen Dialekt ausmacht, und dann zu gucken, was zutrifft. Eine andere wäre, zu untersuchen, was die Leute, die das Wort benutzen, damit meinen. Ich glaube, für manche (mich eingeschlossen) ist es eine Sprache, für andere nicht. Die wirst du dann aber auch mit Argumenten nicht überzeugen können, denn ihre Entscheidung basiert auf „sieht aus wie Fisch, riecht wie Fisch, schmeckt wie Fisch … ist wohl Fisch“

Answer (score 3):

Ein Dialekt ist eine Spezialisierung (also ein Unterbegriff) der Sprachvarietät.

Dementsprechend ist ein *Dialekt* eine Sprachvarietät, aber zum Beispiel auch die *Jugendsprache*, *Fachsprachen* oder, wie im genannten Zusammenhang, auch *Österreichisches Deutsch*.

> Dialekt: die ursprüngliche, landschaftlich verschiedene Redeweise
>   einer Region im Gegensatz zur dort geltenden Schrift- und
>   Umgangssprache

Also ist *Österreichisch* kein Dialekt, da es die (in Österreich) geltende *Schrift- und Umgangssprache* ist.

Quellen: [Wiktionary:Sprachvarietät](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sprachvariet%C3%A4t), [Wikitionary:Dialekt](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dialekt)

Comment: Wikipedia spricht auch von einem "Dialektverbund nichtstandardisierter Varietäten" ([Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairische_Dialekte)). Das scheint dann so, als wäre "Dialekt" ein Oberbegriff und die "Varietät" eine Untergruppe eines Dialekts? Aber ich bin kein Linguist...

Comment: Nein. Im Südosten Bayerns wird zwar derselbe Dialekt wie im Norden Salzburgs und im Westen Oberösterreichs gesprochen, aber an den Schulen in Passau wird deutsches Deutsch unterrichtet, während Schüler im nahe gelegenen Braunau österreichisches Deutsch lernen. Der Dialekt ist also KEINE Spezialisierung einer Varietät!