# Auf Östereichisch: was ist die korrekte Form für Zeitangaben in der Vergangenheit?

Tags: austrian

Ich stolperte gerade in einer Übersetzung über die Formulierung *"vor drei Tage"* (anstatt *"vor drei Tagen"*). Wird das so tatsächlich korrekt benutzt (ein Tippfehler wäre gut denkbar)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

»Vor drei Tage« ist falsch. In Deutschland, wie auch in Österreich.

Der Dativ wird im österreichischen Standarddeutsch genau gleich gebildet wie im deutschen Deutsch, und auch die Verwendung ist gleich.

Korrekt ist also:

> Vor drei Tagen.

Diese Antwort gilt, wie erwähnt, für österreichisches Hochdeutsch bzw. österreichisches Standarddeutsch. (Zur Unterscheidung von österreichischem Deutsch zu österreichischen Dialekten siehe [diese Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22401/1487).)

---

Auf die hier gestellte Frage bezogen:

Ich kenne Dialekte die in Österreich gesprochen werden, in denen diese Formulierung so lauten würde:

> voa drei toog
>   vua drei toog
>   vua drei doog
>   (und ähnliche Varianten)

Das rührt daher, dass in diesen Dialekten der Dativ von *toog/doog* zufällig genau gleich gebildet wird wie der Nominativ, mit diesem also identisch ist.

Nachdem sich einzelne Dialekte in der Grammatik relativ stark voneinander unterscheiden können, hat es aber wenig Sinn, hier in allgemeiner Weise auf die donaubairischen Dialekte einzugehen.

Comment: +1 für die Antwort nach dem Edit.