# How is the word “Deutsch” pronounced in different German dialects?

Tags: pronunciation, dialect

How is the word *Deutsch* pronounced in different German dialects/languages?

What are the most deviant examples?

Comment: My apologies for the edit and rollback. Note however that [*deutsch*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/deutsch) and [*Deutsch*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Deutsch) are different words (or at least have different grammatical functions). I did not think of the latter one when I edited.

Comment: You shouldn’t just randomly tag the question with only a few dialects if you are interested in a comparison of all dialects. I have cleaned up the tags.

Comment: I voted to close the topic since to my eye the question "What are the most deviant examples?" is primarily opinion based. What would be an intersubjective meter of 'deviance' in this case?

Comment: I wouldn't read "deviant" here in a negative way. I would read it as: "Which of them are phonetically most different from standard pronunciation?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most deviant examples will probably be found in the most deviant dialects, such as Walliser German *Tiitschu.*

Historically, the *d-* spelling competed with a *t-* spelling, which arose from the Southern pronunciation. The pronunciation with *t-* is still common in Switzerland. Of course, the difference between *t-* and *d-* was quite small, since Southern *t* does (or did) not have any aspiration, and in initial position, unaspirated *t-* is quite close to – though still distinct from – voiceless *d-.* The aspiration of *t* is a Northern German habit (from Low German) that rose to prominence when the Northern German pronunciation became standard. A modern pronunciation makes the word *teutsch* sound far more distinct from *deutsch* than what it used to be, especially considering that in Central German, intitial *t-* was (or is) always weakened to *d-.*

Answer (score 3):

Hier ein paar Formen aus südlichen Regionen (geschrieben so, dass es der Aussprache halbwegs nahe kommt):

Schwäbisch: **dejtsch** (*en dr dejtscha Schbrôôch* - in der deutschen Sprache)

Bairisch: **daitsch** (*in da daitschn Schbrochn*)

in Österreich: **daitsch** (korrigiert, siehe Kommentar)

Schweizerdeutsch: **düütsch** (auch hier sind viele Varietäten verbreitet)

Sächsisch: **dyitsch** (wobei y hier für einen Schwa-Laut stehen soll, also für einen charakterlosen Zentralvokal, der zwischen allen Stühlen sitzt)

Comment: 1. Ich lebe seit 52 Jahren in Österreich und habe weder in Österreich, noch sonstwo jemals »däätsch« gehört. 2. In Österreich gibt es genau eine Standardvarietät (nämlich »österreichisches Deutsch«) aber eine sehr großer Zahl verschiedener Dialekte.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, das zeigt nur, dass das "Standard" in "Standardvarietät" nicht redundant ist.

Comment: Ich musste das korrigieren, weil »*Österreichisch: däätsch*« gleich aus zwei Gründen falsch ist. 1. »Österreichisch« ist keine Sprache, keine Sprachvarietät und kein Dialekt. Es gibt: »Österreichisches Deutsch«, das ist eine Standardvarietät (in dieser Varietät lautet das gefragte Wort: »deutsch«) und er gibt Dialekte, die in Österreich gesprochen werden. Siehe auch diese Frage https://german.stackexchange.com/q/22400/1487 und diese dazugehörende Antwort, die Takkat aus unerfindlichen Gründen zu einer anderen Frage verschoben hat: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22401/1487

Comment: (Fortsetzung) 2. »däätsch« habe ich noch nie gehört. Das ist schlechtweg frei erfunden, und klingt für mich nach einem deutschen Comedian oder Showmaster, der noch nie in Österreich war, und in völliger Unkenntnis der Tatsachen eine Karikatur des Wiener Dialekts versucht.

Comment: Ich glaube, dass mit "däätsch" die rezente Wiener Aussprache gemeint ist, die die Monophthongierung von ai zu ä: aufweist (analoge Beispiele: Meidling > Mä:dling, Eis > Ä:s ...)

Answer (score 2):

"Plattdüütsch" = Plattdeutsch, also Düütsch für Deutsch

Die norddeutschen Mundarten/Sprachen haben übrigens sehr viel mehr Ähnlichkeit mit z.B. dem Holländischen als die süddeutschen. Interessant ist es dabei auch in diesem Zusammenhang, sich einmal mit der zweiten deutschen Lautverschiebung zu beschäftigen. Dazu findet man z.B. auch einen Artikel bei Wikipedia.