# What are the resources to learn to pronouce words the right way?

Tags: pronunciation, resource, online-resource

I have just decided to learn German. I want to pronounce things the right way. I started with [Pimsleur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimsleur_method), but when I compared the pronunciation with Google Translate, it was very different. So what is the correct pronunciation? Google Translate or Pimsleur audio?

The word is "Entschuldigung".

In general, what are good resources to learn the right way of pronunciation? Pimsleur? Google? Or something else?

Comment: Don't know the pronunciation from Pimsleur, but I'm pretty sure that it's fine. Can you provide an audio example? Google Translate pronunciation is OK, but not what I'd recommend.

Comment: There is no single correct pronunciation, see e.g. http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11075/how-to-pronounce-universit%c3%a4t (and many more).

Comment: @Em1 , What do you recommend ?

Comment: Your user name is not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc), a lot of the words have recordings from native speakers

[image: recordings]

Comment: I noticed that when I press the figure twice I get two different voices, Why is that ?

Comment: @MathsLover I guess you hear a different recording. There are sometimes more than 1 recording. As you see in the screenshot, you can choose between which recording you want to listen to.

Answer (score 0):

The word "Entschuldigung" on google translator is ok. But no speech synthesis can beat a real person talking!

I recommend watching movies in german, first with subtitles, then maybe movies you already know but without subtitles...
Listen to german radio stations via internet or hang around a family that speaks german a lot within the family!

I have experienced that hearing people talk a lot and observing them helped me learning different languages properly.

Comment: I have just started the journey! I can't even say "german is cool" in german!

Comment: Then remember of this advice when you feel like you are able to understand somebody talking! Wish you success and fun!